# Not able to separate radio button from label

Tags: html, css, angular

```
<div class="questions" style="font-size:13pt;margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:10px;">
  <p class="question" id="ques{{i+1}}" style="font-size:17pt;font-weight:normal">{{i+1+". "+a.question}}</p>
  <img *ngIf="isImage[i]" [src]="a.image" class="img-responsive" style="height:30%;width:30%;padding-left:20px;border-radius: 0;">
</div>
<div style="font-weight:normal;font-size:15pt;margin-left:20px">
  <form name="quizform" id="option">
    <label id="label_1_{{i}}"><input id="1_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option1}}"> A)  {{a.option1}}</label><br/>
    <!-- [(ngModel)]="ans.answer"   (click)="getAnswer(i,$event.target.value,$event.target.id)"  -->
    <label id="label_2_{{i}}"><input id="2_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option2}}"> B)  {{a.option2}}</label><br/>
    <label id="label_3_{{i}}"><input id="3_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option3}}"> C)  {{a.option3}}</label><br/>
    <label id="label_4_{{i}}"><input id="4_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option4}}"> D)  {{a.option4}}</label><br/><br/>
  </form>
</div>
```

I want to add radio button inside the label so that whenever user click on label radio button is selected but what i face is [it overlap on label tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY7rI.png)
Here my css file look like

```
#option {
  margin-left: 10px!important;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

label {
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-top: -10px
}

#quiz {
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to work with `<laber for="..">` and remove the `position: absolute;`

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp

```css
#option {
  margin-left: 10px!important;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

label {
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-top: -10px
}

#quiz {
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="questions" style="font-size:13pt;margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:10px;">
    
              <p class="question" id="ques{{i+1}}" style="font-size:17pt;font-weight:normal">{{i+1+".  "+a.question}}</p>
    
              <img *ngIf="isImage[i]" [src]="a.image" class="img-responsive" style="height:30%;width:30%;padding-left:20px;border-radius: 0;">
            </div>
    
    
         <div style="font-weight:normal;font-size:15pt;margin-left:20px">
           <form name="quizform" id="option">
             <input id="1_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option1}}"><label for="1_{{i}}" id="label_1_{{i}}"> A)  {{a.option1}}</label><br/>   <!-- [(ngModel)]="ans.answer"   (click)="getAnswer(i,$event.target.value,$event.target.id)"  -->
             <input id="2_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option2}}"><label for="2_{{i}}" id="label_2_{{i}}"> B)  {{a.option2}}</label><br/>
             <input id="3_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option3}}"><label for="3_{{i}}" id="label_3_{{i}}"> C)  {{a.option3}}</label><br/>
             <input id="4_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option4}}"><label for="4_{{i}}" id="label_4_{{i}}"> D)  {{a.option4}}</label><br/><br/>
           </form>
         </div>
```

Comment: still radio button overlap on label

Comment: @SidKasundra is it now okay?

Comment: @SidKasundra this perfect answer for your question. If radio button still overlap then check your other CSS that affect your HTML

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to give `position:absolute` to input. just remove absolute an remove `padding-left` from the label if you don't want `padding-left` in label.

```css
#option{
margin-left:10px!important;}

#wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;} 

label{
font-size:16pt;
font-weight:normal;
}

#quiz{
width:75%;
height:auto;
margin-top:15px;
text-align:left;
padding:0px 50px 0px 50px;
margin-bottom:20px;}
```

```html
<div class="questions" style="font-size:13pt;margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:10px;">

     <p class="question" id="ques{{i+1}}" style="font-size:17pt;font-weight:normal">{{i+1+".  "+a.question}}</p>

     <img *ngIf="isImage[i]" [src]="a.image" class="img-responsive" style="height:30%;width:30%;padding-left:20px;border-radius: 0;">
   </div>


<div style="font-weight:normal;font-size:15pt;margin-left:20px">
  <form name="quizform" id="option">
    <label id="label_1_{{i}}"><input id="1_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option1}}"> A)  {{a.option1}}</label><br/> 
    <label id="label_2_{{i}}"><input id="2_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option2}}"> B)  {{a.option2}}</label><br/>
    <label id="label_3_{{i}}"><input id="3_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option3}}"> C)  {{a.option3}}</label><br/>
    <label id="label_4_{{i}}"><input id="4_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option4}}"> D)  {{a.option4}}</label><br/><br/>
  </form>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use position:relative instead of absolute

```css
#option input{
  margin-left: 10px!important;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

label {
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-top: -10px
}

#quiz {
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input {
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="questions" style="font-size:13pt;margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:10px;">
  <p class="question" id="ques{{i+1}}" style="font-size:17pt;font-weight:normal">{{i+1+". "+a.question}}</p>
  <img *ngIf="isImage[i]" [src]="a.image" class="img-responsive" style="height:30%;width:30%;padding-left:20px;border-radius: 0;">
</div>
<div style="font-weight:normal;font-size:15pt;margin-left:20px">
  <form name="quizform" id="option">
    <label id="label_1_{{i}}">
    <input id="1_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option1}}"> A)  {{a.option1}}</label><br/>
    <!-- [(ngModel)]="ans.answer"   (click)="getAnswer(i,$event.target.value,$event.target.id)"  -->
    <label id="label_2_{{i}}"><input id="2_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option2}}"> B)  {{a.option2}}</label><br/>
    <label id="label_3_{{i}}"><input id="3_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option3}}"> C)  {{a.option3}}</label><br/>
    <label id="label_4_{{i}}"><input id="4_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option4}}"> D)  {{a.option4}}</label><br/><br/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Often with CSS it is the case where too much is attempted.  In this case, take the `position:absolute` off the `input`

It is also often made more difficult to style when embedded style is mixed with CSS.  Here I have simply moved it to the CSS.

Lastly, you use `<br>` to simulate block display so we do that with css

```css
#option {
  margin-left: 10px!important;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

label {
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-left: 15px;
  display:block;
}

#quiz {
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.questions{font-size:13pt;margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:10px;}
.question {font-size:17pt;font-weight:normal;}
.img-responsive{height:30%;width:30%;padding-left:20px;border-radius: 0;}
.form-container{font-weight:normal;font-size:15pt;margin-left:20px;}
```

```html
<div class="questions" >
  <p class="question" id="ques{{i+1}}">{{i+1+". "+a.question}}</p>
  <img *ngIf="isImage[i]" [src]="a.image" class="img-responsive" >
</div>
<div class="form-container">
  <form name="quizform" id="option">
    <label id="label_1_{{i}}"><input id="1_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option1}}"> A)  {{a.option1}}</label>
    <label id="label_2_{{i}}"><input id="2_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option2}}"> B)  {{a.option2}}</label>
    <label id="label_3_{{i}}"><input id="3_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option3}}"> C)  {{a.option3}}</label>
    <label id="label_4_{{i}}"><input id="4_{{i}}" type="radio"  name="q{{i}}" value="{{a.option4}}"> D)  {{a.option4}}</label>
  </form>
</div>
```